# rsync from mac to Windows 10 via SSH / Cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin, openssh

I set up Windows 10's OpenSSH Server which works fine.

In order to use rsync on Windows, I installed Cygwin. That works also fine.

Now I set Cygwin as the standard shell for SSH connections:

```
$ New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat" -PropertyType String -Force
```

When I connect to the Windows machine via SSH Cygwin opens as expected.
I can rsync folders on the computer just fine:

```
$ rsync -a  /cygdrive/c/source/ /cygdrive/f/target/
```

But once I try to rsync from my mac to the target I get an error:

```
$ rsync -a /Users/mac/test/ username@10.0.0.11:/backup

bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Any idead how to solve that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing!

Comment: My question about how to diff folders from Mac to PC on same network: https://superuser.com/questions/1462861/diff-directory-contents-from-mac-to-pc-on-same-network

Comment: @Ryan I made it work by setting the path to the actual bash executable (bash.exe) instead of setting it to Cygwin.bat :-)
I also choose to use "bitvise" (which is free for private use) - works like a charm!